# vi command: copy all the lines to clipboard from remote file and paste them to an host editor

Tags: macos, ssh, vi

I would like to know which command to use in order to copy all the lines of a file text to my host pc from a remote file accessed via ssh using the vi command.

To be more clear:

1. Access via ssh to a remote host
2. Inspect a remote file using vi
3. Copy all lines of the file to my host clipboard
4. Paste all the lines to a Text Editor on my host pc

How to do that?
I've tried this command:

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

It says that the lines are copied to the registry, but if I try to paste the lines to my text editor (point 4), the clipboard doesn't contains the lines.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Note: My host is a Mac OS X.

Comment: Why don't you copy the entire file with `scp` on your own machine and do the vi on your local machine?

Comment: Yes, it could be a solution, but how to do that while I'm in the remote host via ssh? Via scp command?

Comment: If you are on the remote host:
`scp file user@local.ip:/path/to/folder`

Or you could logout from remote and from your local machine you run
`scp user@remote:/path/to/file /path/to/local/folder`

Comment: "local.ip" is what I obtain with ifconfig on my host, right?

Comment: In principle yes, but in practice it is a bit more complicated than that, especially if you are at home on your own network, because you need your public ip, and I'm not sure if you need some port forwarding. The second solution is easier.

Comment: Right, it seems nice. But I can't execute it if I don't know yet the full path of the file to inspect!

Comment: There are many ways you can do this. 1 - you can login to remote, look for the file and run `pwd` before you logout, so you have the path printed. 2 - if you have a linux command to search for your file, you could run `ssh user@remote "search_command"` to have the location of your file printed out.

Comment: Yeah, I only want to avoid to logout from the ssh session and do all with only one connection

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you cannot select all the text you want from the screen and cmd-C (copy) to the pasteboard, on MacOS? (And clipboard, in other OSs).

Is it the entire file you need? Since you are accessing it via ssh you can also paste to the pasteboard from the command line:

```
$ ssh remote-svr cat ./subdir/location/textfile | pbcopy
```

Now cmd-V to paste, where you want, locally.

Looked at, another way,

1. `ssh remove-svr` accesses the remote server (though not interactively)
2. to run `cat ./subdir/location/textfile`, which outputs the file's content to stdout
3. ssh captures that output and sends it to local stdout
4. `| pbcopy` pipes the stdout from ssh to the `pbcopy` filter which puts it on the local pasteboard.

Comment: A question: the command you posted can work also when you are logged in the remote host via ssh?

Comment: `pbcopy` is a local, MacOS command, so I would be surprised if it works across `ssh`. My solution runs `cat` remotely, but `ssh` spills the output to stdout, which pbcopy can capture.

Comment: So your command has to be launched before logging via ssh, right?

Comment: As, shown, you are using ssh to access the file to copy its contents to stdout, locally. This is not using an interactive ssh session.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The problem is that can't be executed if you don't know yet the remote path of the file to inspect. So this is the reason why I had to access to the remote host before, find the file, and copy it (to the host or directly his content to the clipboard) when it was found.

Comment: You can (1) ssh interactively to find the file and verify its contents, then (2) note the file's path and logout of the remote machine, then (3) use the command I suggested.

Comment: Yes, it can be a right solution. Any way to avoid the logout/relogin with the command?

Comment: Sort of... you can run each of the commands you'd do interactively, locally, similar to how I showed running `cat`. So, you can run `ls -l`_path_, for example, to list files. Use `cat` rather than `vi` to see their content, before piping to `pbcopy`. If it is a hassle to run ssh because of passwords, try to set up public/private keys to bypass passwords (see `ssh-keygen`)